# JS Substring between word and space

Tags: node.js, substring, indexof, discord.js, lastindexof

I have a string like

"username 234234 some text"

And I would like to devide them in

"username"

"234234"

and "some text"

I tried with split and substring but failed with finding the second space, most often a blank text got returned.

Thank you very much!

Comment: can you show us what you did try?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this may help:

```
let str = "username 234234 some text";
let arr = str.split(" ");
let username = arr[0];
let num = arr[1];
let otherText = arr.slice(2).join(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this regex `/(?<first>.+) (?<second>[0-9]+) (?<third>.+)/g`

```
const testString = "username 234234 some text";
const reg = /(?<first>.+) (?<second>[0-9]+) (?<third>.+)/g;
const matches = reg.exec(myString);
console.log(matches[0]); // username
console.log(matches[1]); // 234234
console.log(matches[2]); // some text
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for a discord.js project because you used the tag "discord.js":

```
const content = message.content.split(" ");
console.log(content) // will log the entire message

content = content.slice(0, 1);
console.log(content) // will log you the username

content = content.slice(1, 2);
console.log(content) // will log you the number

content = content.slice(2);
console.log(content) // will log you the text
```